# How to search for any combination of one or more words, regardless of their order using Android Room

Tags: android, sql, full-text-search, android-room

I have been able to achieve a basic search capability in Android Room + FTS with the following query as an example in my Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Conversation JOIN ConversationFts ON Conversation.id == ConversationFts.id WHERE ConversationFts.title LIKE :text GROUP BY Conversation.id")
public abstract DataSource.Factory<Integer, Conversation> search(String text);
```

Where the `text` is passed along between percentage characters, as such `%lorem%`.

This example works perfectly for the search of a single word and I want to expand this to be able to search for one or more words with the condition that they do not need to be in the order they are entered, but they must have a match for all the words. This means this has to be an `AND` and not `OR` situation.

I've found a few examples of SQL queries, but they require a specific query tailored for each case, for example: LIKE text AND LIKE another AND LIKE, *etc*... which is not a solution.

How can this be achieved? And to make it clear, I am not looking for a raw query solution, I want to stick to Room as much as possible, otherwise, I'd rather just use this as it is than to resort to raw queries.

---

**EDIT:** Adding an example per request

I search for `do` the results returned include all matches that contain `do` in the title, even if it is a partial match

I search for `do` and `test` the results returned include all matches that contain `do` and `test`, but in no specific order, even if they are partial matches.

However, if just one of them cannot be found in the text then it will not be returned in the results. For example, if `do` is found, but `test` is not then it will not be part of the results.

Comment: "which is not a solution" -- why not?

Comment: @CommonsWare That means building a raw query instead of passing just a list of words, which is not what I'm looking for here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no way to do that except creating a raw query dynamically. You can write another method, something like this:

```
public abstract class ConversationDao {

    public DataSource.Factory<Integer, Conversation> search(String text) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String[] words = text.split("\\s+");

        if (words.length > 0) {
            builder.append(" WHERE ");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            builder.append("ConversationFts.title LIKE %").append(words[i]).append("%");
            if (i < words.length - 1) {
                builder.append(" AND ");
            }
        }

        SupportSQLiteQuery query = new SimpleSQLiteQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM Conversation JOIN ConversationFts ON Conversation.id == ConversationFts.id"
                        + builder.toString()
                        + " GROUP BY Conversation.id"
        );
        
        return search(query);
    }

    @RawQuery
    public abstract DataSource.Factory<Integer, Conversation> search(SupportSQLiteQuery query);

}
```

Comment: Resorting to raw queries is not my goal here, but disregarding that your example appears to be exactly like the others I found which follows the order of the words, when I want the order of the words to not matter. i.e. if I search `hey` and `you` I want all matches containing those words, no matter in which order they are in.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such functionality in SQL like what you want. By the way, the above solution does not care about the order of words. Each word should satisfy a separate clause and their order doesn't matter. I guess I forgot `%` in `LIKE` clauses.

Comment: I've kept looking for another way to do this, but like you said there - there is none. As a result I'll accept your answer since it does what I want, even though not the way I wanted. This sounds like an sql injection nightmare waiting to happen